# jsf - validate date with expression language

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to check the value of my birthdate input field. There should be several possibilities: `dd.MM.yyyy`, `dd.M.yyyy`, `d.MM.yyyy`, `d.m.yyyy` and also `dd.MM.yy`, `dd.M.yy`, `d.MM.yy`, `d.m.yy`. For example you can input 07.03.1993, 7.3.93 or whatever.

The following regex example just checks the format validation, but it doesn't check if the date exists (e.g. 29.02.2011 or 47.02.2011 will be allowed)

```
String s = (String) arg2;
        String pattern = "^(\\d{2}|\\d{1})\\.(\\d{2}|\\d{1})\\.(\\d{2}|\\d{4})$";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(("date correct"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("date incorrect");
        }
```

edit: I just created the following regex statement, now it checks if the month is bigger than 12 and the day is bigger than 31. I think I should use regex first and then validate the date with `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String s = "^((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\.(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\.((19|20)\\d{2})$";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If regex is not a must, you can try and convert your string to a date using the `parse` method of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and see if it succeeds.

If it does (you get a valid `Date` object), you have a valid date entered in your form (or input). If it does not succeed, the `parse` function returns `null` and the `String` you input was invalid.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)'s the javadoc for the `parse` method.

EDIT: For the extra validation in case you don't want to use `setLenient`, you can use the `Date` that you get from `parse` and convert it back to a `String` using the same format. Then just compare the `String` resulting from the conversion with the one you supply as input. If they match, you've got valid input.

Comment: the parse method will allow a 29.02 date for a non-leap year

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse` does no validation. E.g. if you do   `Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-01-32");`, then the Date d will refer to February 1:st, because the days "overflow" into the month.

Comment: That's not true Alderath, use `setLenient(false)`, then your date will give an exception

Comment: You can add some more validation by determining the leap years and checking for **29/02**. But still, if the parse method allows for **29/02** in a non-leap year, what will the `Date` contain? I don't think the `Date` object returned will allow **29/02** in a non-leap year. You could try and use the static method `java.sql.Date.valueOf` and use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Thanks @lucian.pantelimon, I'll combine your `SimpleDateFormat` with my regular expression. I'll show you if it works

Comment: @YvesBeutler Nice. I missed that. I was surprised when I notice that no exceptions were thrown. Imo, setLenient(false) should be default instead of the other way around. When calling parse, you expect to have errors reported.

Comment: @Yves Beutler I've updated my answer so that you don't need to do a regex match for the extra validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it to get day and month parts of the date.

Then you can do something like:

```
final int dayToCheck = 32; // user input
final int month = 2; // user input
final int year = 1981; // user input        

final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, 1); // day doesn't need to be the user input, it can be any day in the month you want to check

if (cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > dayToCheck) {

    // the day is invalid
}
if (cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dayToCheck) {

    // again, the day is invalid
}
```

You can do the same check with the `Calendar.MONTH` field.

I haven't checked if this compiles, but you should get the idea.

Comment: There won't be an error if you write `cal.set(2011,02,29)`. So I prefer @lucian.pantelimon's solution and combined it with my work.

Comment: @YvesBeutler As I stated in the answer: You must not set the complete user input when you create the calendar. You need to set the year and the month only (you can always set 1 for the day). Then use `cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` to compare it to the user input for the day.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I think it's a better way to let the `SimpleDateFormat` check if the date is correct than a selfmade solution like yours.